# Not connecting to servers for Fifa 15 UT

Tags: technical-issues, fifa-15

I downloaded Fifa 15 UT from windows 10 store, it was 1 GB game, but now when I open the game it keeps saying connecting to servers but it never does. Does any of you face similar problem. Is there any solution to this problem?

My laptop is currently running on Windows 10 64 bit. My laptop configuration is:

4GB Ram, i5 processor memory 1 TB, intel HD graphics 4000

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the server is down.  Lots of people are reporting it: http://downdetector.com/status/ea/map/

The solution is to wait until EA fixes the server.  There's a scheduled maintenance today, possibly to fix whatever issues are causing this downtime: https://twitter.com/EASPORTSFIFA/status/707762920785125377